# What is a good training program for a Quidditch Snitch?

Tags: training

For those of you who aren't Harry Potter fans, Quidditch is a wizard sport played on broomstick that has been modified for us non-flying people and is now pretty popular ([Quidditch World Cup](http://www.internationalquidditch.org/worldcup/) is coming up on November 12th-13th in NYC). In Harry Potter, a Quidditch Game ends when the [Seeker](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Seeker) catches the flying [Snitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quidditch#The_Golden_Snitch). In the modified muggle version, the Snitch is played by a person who isn't a part of either team, and his/her goal is basically to run away from the Seekers.

I found [this article](http://www.fitnessmagazine.com/blogs/fitstop/2011/07/15/fitness/harry-potter-and-the-wizardly-workout/) about training tips for Quidditch positions, but all it says about training to be a Snitch is to try cardio kickboxing, and that cross country runners are ideal candidates. How else could I train to build up my speed so that I can run away from the Seekers for a sustained period of time?

Comment: I don't even get how people can run fast with a broom between their legs...

Comment: Some sort of high-intensity interval training (HIIT) sounds like a good idea, Tabata is a popular regimen (20 seconds hard work, 10 seconds rest, repeat 8 times). You can do this with running, or eg. with burpees to push your cardiovascular system.

Comment: This made me laugh :9

Answer (score 5):

I watched a few matches, and those things you mentioned are great starts to help keep the seekers away.  If you are building up your running speed and endurance, run 400s around a track (just once around).  Get around the track in a set time, then take a break for a set time limit, and then go again.  For instance, 3 minutes to get around followed by a 2 minute break.  If you get around in 2 minutes, then you get a 3 minute break.  If you get around in 4 minutes, you only get a 1 minute break.  Stick with the times and push yourself.  Every time you do this, you can drop either the break time or the lap time.  Remember to warm up and cool down with atleast 5-10 minutes of jogging.

Also important, speed can be increased by doing sprints and leg workouts (squats, leg press, leg extensions, calf raises, leg curls).  Put some size on and train sprints by running shuttles or dashes.

Good luck with the position!

Answer (score 4):

One thing usually neglected in training is explosive starting speed, which a good snitch would need. There are some great solo exercises for this, although partner drills work better.

Here's a quick list:

- Sled/tire pulls and/or chute runs (also improves stride length)
- Skips (aiming for either vertical or horizontal max)
- Falling starts (lean forward until you lose your balance, catch yourself by accelerating full-speed for 20-30 yards... I love this one for some reason)
- "Gears" drills (see lame ASCII art below), these are *great* for games like this. Or soccer.
- Partner-resisted starts, tubing acceleration drills, etc.

Gears are cool, and can be done with directional changes as well.

```
  ^-- 2nd gear --^-- 3nd gear --^-- 1st gear --^-- 4th gear --^
  |
  \- that's a cone
```

Being able to change accelerations is important, plus being able to do so throws off an opponent's ability to predict where you're going to be.

Typical ladder drills aren't so much for endurance but for the ability to turn and develop proprioception ("where am I in space, and how do I make this maneuver without tripping myself").